# How can I use modus ponens or modus tollens to produce valid arguments?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

*I know this one is:*

$(1)$ If logic is easy, then I am a monkey’s uncle.

I am not a monkey’s uncle.

∴ ?

My answer: $\therefore$ Logic is not easy.

---

(2) *Can someone help me with this one?*

If this figure is a quadrilateral, then the sum of its interior angles is 360◦.

The sum of the interior angles of this figure is not 360◦.

∴ ?

---

(3) *Another which has me stuck:*

If they were unsure of the address, then they would have telephoned.

?

∴They were sure of the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are examples of modus tollens.

$P \rightarrow Q$

$\lnot Q$

$\therefore \lnot P$.

---

In the second, 
$P$ = this figure is a quadrilateral, $Q$ = then the sum of its interior angles is 360◦.

$\lnot Q$ = The sum of the interior angles of this figure is not 360◦.

So we conclude, by modus tollens, that $\lnot P$: This figure is not a quadrilateral.

---

In the third, the missing line will be the *negation* of "they would have telephoned."

Answer (score 0):

It's completely analagous.  The first one is the figure is not a quadrilateral, the second one would be they didn't telephone.  ((If A then B)  &  not B)  =>  not A, plug in various phrases for A and B.